# sql find average from counting?

Tags: sql, count, average

So I have the query:

```
select states, count(numberofcounty) 
from countytable 
group by states  
order by count(distinct numberofcounty) ASC;
```

which return a table of 2 columns: number of state and number of county from least to most. 
How can I get the avg of how many county are there per state in a single real number?

The table structure is:

```
create table numberofcounty(
    numberofcounty text, 
    states text references states(states), 
);
create table states (
    states text primary key,  
    name text, 
    admitted_to_union text
```

);

Comment: Can you post your table structure?

Comment: How many countries are there per state? Doesn't it how many states per country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be it?

```
countytable:
state|county
a     aa
a     ab
a     ac
b     ba


SELECT AVG(counties) FROM (SELECT state, COUNT(county) as counties FROM countytable GROUP BY state) as temp
```

result: 2

Answer (score 2):

You can use your current query as a subquery to one that gets the average of the number of counties per state

```
Select avg (c) average_counties
From (select count(numberofcounty) c
from countytable 
group by states) s
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not missing anything, this should essentially give you the same result as the double grouping method in other answers:

```
SELECT COUNT(numberofcounty) / COUNT(DISTINCT states)
FROM countytable
;
```